# C++ overloading the = operator

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++

When overloading the = operator, should one make the contents of one object equal to the contents of the other object OR do you make the pointer of the object point to the same object?

Reading back on the question it seems that the contents should be copied and not the pointers. But I just can't figure it out, So I would be grateful if someone would explain what I should do, I know how to do both, I'm just not sure which one to choose.

```
class IntObject
{
private:
    int *pi_One;

public:

    IntObject(void);

    IntObject::IntObject(int const &i_one);

    ~IntObject(void);

    IntObject & operator=(const IntObject&);

};

IntObject::IntObject()
{
    pi_One = new int(0); 
}

IntObject::IntObject(int const &i_one)
{
    pi_One = new int(i_one); 
}

IntObject::~IntObject(void)
{
    delete pi_One;
}

IntObject & IntObject::operator=(const IntObject& c) {
//This copies the pointer to the ints
    this->pi_One = c.pi_One;

    return *this;  
}
```

Comment: Pointers already implicitly implement the = operator. So it's not clear how you would even override that. I suggest you give an example of two versions you're contemplating.

Comment: If you're struggling to figure this out you should probably read the excellent `Effective C++` and follow up books by Scott Meyers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what semantics you want to have in your type. If you want value semantics, then copy the contents (deep copy, as is the case in `std::vector`), if you want reference semantics (shallow copy, as in `std::shared_ptr`)

Comment: The semantics can be deduces from `IntObject::~IntObject`. Since it deletes `pi_One`, the class has value semantics, and needs a deep copy. A shallow copy would leak the old pointer and double-delete the new.

Comment: @MSalters: You are right in that the current implementation leads to that conclusion, agreed. (The question of whether the current implementation models the intention or not is a different issue :) )

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely copy the contents, not the pointers. Think about what you will do when one of the objects which both hold the same pointer is destroyed; you can't delete the pointer because the other object would be affected as well, but you can't not delete it either because you'd cause memory leaks. You'd have to use reference counting and everything would get a whole lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The contents should be copied (in fact, changing the pointer of the object shouldn't actually be possible - I can't imagine how you would do that - and even if it is somehow, you're not supposed to do it). You also have to take care of the differences between deep and shallow copies, especially if your class contains pointers (or containers with pointers in them).

Now that I think about it, I'm not even sure *which* pointer you could possibly want to reassign. Unless you are already working with a pointer - those already have an '=' operator that shouldn't be overloaded though.

Answer (score 0):

The principle of least astonishment would say to copy the content. When using `operator=` on any other object, you wouldn't expect it to copy pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your destructor as it is, then you should change assignment overload. It would be also wise that nobody is attempting assigning IntObject to itself:

```
IntObject & IntObject::operator=(const IntObject& c) {
    if (this != &c)
    {
        //This copies the pointer to the ints
        *this->pi_One = *c.pi_One;
    }
    return *this;  
}
```

Otherwise, there will be attempt to free freed memory in IntObject's destructor

Comment: The comment is wrong: your code assigns the `int`, not the `int*`. Therefore, it is perfectly fine to omit the `if` statement as well. `*this->pi_One = *this->pi_One` is a valid assignment. (Removing the `if` generates better code. CPU's don't like branches).

Comment: I agree in this very case not much (if at all) time would be saved. I value your deep knowledge of CPU internals and how you imply pipeline is flushed upon branching, but "the least astonishment principle" suggests my comment is not wrong as such ;)

Comment: The check in general is a red flag. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom. In this case copy-and-swap isn't necessary, but for the same reasons the check is equally redundant.